# How to include a css file using R code in the yaml header?

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown

How to include a css file using R code in the yaml header?

I have the following directory tree

```
./
./include/
./include/css/
./include/css/style.css
./docs
./docs/report/
./docs/report/report.Rmd
```

and I have tried

```
css: "`r library(here); here('include/css/style.css')`"
```

but it didn't work and gives the following error

> File `r here::here('include/css/style.css')` not found in resource
> path Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99

Comment: Did you examine the output HTML to check what CSS path gets inserted? Also, instead of `library(here); here(…)` I suggest using `here::here(…)`. It’s more concise and there’s no need to attach the package.

Comment: @KonradRudolph
"File `r here::here('include/css/style.css')` not found in resource path
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99"

Answer (score 0):

I am new, so can't comment on your post yet.

I use this example for my bookdown documents:

https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-css.html

This works well, but I put all my css files on the same directory along with markdown and yml files.

If you want to use your directory structure, maybe a relative path might work.
Here is an example I found:

https://github.com/fletcher/MultiMarkdown/issues/47

Good luck!