# Calling a css file from a yaml file in R Quarto

Tags: css, r, yaml, quarto

I would like to call a css file from a yaml file for my R Quarto Book.  The css file contains the theme for my Quarto document.  (I want the team to use the same css file so that our Quarto docs have the same look and feel).  If I call the file directly then I can see it working as I expect where I can control font, and font size etc.  I receive an error when I try and put the css file in a directory structure.

ERROR: TypeError: Path must be a string. Received {"value":"here::here("one_care_custom.scss")","tag":"!expr"}

my_cusom_theme.css is placed in the root directory of the R project.
This code summaries what works and what does not.

```
format:
  html:
    theme:
      - cosmo
      #- !expr here::here("my_custom_theme.scss") # This fails
      - here::here("my_custom_theme.scss") # This fails
      #- my_custom_theme.scss # this works
```

I've came across this post which I can't get to work [How to include a css file using R code in the yaml header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71079999/how-to-include-a-css-file-using-r-code-in-the-yaml-header) and have also been guided by https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/2470
.  Would anyone be able to offer any tips?

Ultimately I'm trying to call my_custom_theme.css from a specific directory which the team can see but I'm failing at the first hurdle.

Thank you, Phil,

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
---
format:
  html:
    theme:
      - cosmo
      - "`r here::here('my_custom_theme.scss')`"
---
```

Comment: No! But thank you for the suggestion.  I get the feeling it wants to look in the directory C:\PROGRA~1\RStudio\RESOUR~1\app\bin\quarto\share\formats\html\bootstrap\themes\ to find the custom theme.

This is the error I get after trying out your suggestion:-

Error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (os error 123), stat 'C:\PROGRA~1\RStudio\RESOUR~1\app\bin\quarto\share\formats\html\bootstrap\themes\`r here::here('my_custom.scss')`.scss'

My customized theme is in the root directory of my R Studio project.

Comment: what quarto version are you using?